# calling js function in html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, smart-wizard

i am trying to call the function i added to the smartWizard js which is

*smartWizard.js*

```
function changeConfirmButton(){
    $(btConfirm).removeClass("buttonDisabled");
}
```

i tested it by calling in the js and it work fine as i intended

```
changeConfirmButton();
```

but what i want is execute the function when pressing a button in html

*index.html*

-initialize

```
$('#wizard').smartWizard();
```

-button

```
<input id="clickMe" type="button" value="clickme" onClick="executeTest();" />
```

-java script function in index.html

```
function executeTest(){
    $('#wizard').smartWizard('changeConfirmButton');
}
```

ีbut when i click the button nothing happen as if i can't call the function changeConfirmButton(); What wrong with my code ? thank you in advance!

Comment: you use only one button in this code? provide html code or jsfiddle

Answer (score 2):

Simply include the smartWizard js file in html and modify your `executeTest` as below

```
 function executeTest(){
    changeConfirmButton();
}
```